# How to disable Deactivate event trigger when NFC detected?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, nfc

I have been using 
so.ane.android.nfc.foreground.dispatch.NFCForegroundDispatch
to detect NFC cards; however, when card detected, a Deactivate event is triggered and it conflicts the client's requirement which the app must return to first view when deactivate event triggers. Since the deactivate event triggers before NFCForegroundDispatchEvent I have no way to distinguish the source of deactivate event is from Android hardware button or the NFC. Appreciate for any workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is no way to disable the event triggered by the NFC.

I used a workaround to diff the time between Activated and Deactivated, on the Android devices I have tested, the difference should less than 200ms. Value higher than this threshold classify as leaving the app and switch back to first view.

Hope this help people who have similar problem.